# Asp.Net MVC Core - Post Action passes old model data to different view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

**Product Model Class**

```
 public class Product
    {
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Home Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EditProduct()
    {
        Product product = new Product()
        {
            ProductId = Guid.Empty,
            Name = "Abc"
        };


        return View(product);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditProduct(Product product)
    {
        Product productCopy = new Product()
        {
            ProductId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = product.Name + "d"
        };

        return View("EditProductCopy", productCopy);
    }

}
```

**EditProduct View**

Note: Auto Generated from Product Model Class,
EditProductCopy is similar, only title is different

```
@model WebApplicationTest.Models.Product

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EditProductCopy";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>EditProductCopy</h1>

<h4>Product</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="EditProduct">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProductId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

I call "EditProduct" view. I don't change anything and I click the "Save" button. "EditProductCopy" view is rendered and I expect to see that new ProductId and "Abcd" as Product name. But I see last posted data (ProductId is empty guid and Name is "abc") What is the reason of this problem?

Project Files can be downloaded from this link:
[Project Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Si2edRUgkaBwr9C5psXYML_uTG6rlJ6p/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default TagHelper display ModelState value not Model.Just add `ModelState.Clear()` before you `return View`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditProduct(Product product)
{
    Product productCopy = new Product()
    {
        ProductId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = product.Name + "d"
    };

    ModelState.Clear();//add this line...

    return View("EditProductCopy", productCopy);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: thank you. Why should we clear model state? View is different and also model is different. Is it bug or not?

Comment: I define new Class such as "Computer" and property names are the same (ProductId and Name). When I define model type as Computer in EditProductCopy view and send new Computer object. There is no change. TagHelper doesn't check Model type and View. If property names are the same, it uses. I think TagHelper should check Model type is equal or not with the new model type

Answer (score 0):

The request is submitted with GET method because method attribute of the form is not specified. So, write `method="POST"` in the form.

Comment: <form asp-action=....> tag adds method="post" in runtime

Comment: Sorry about that.